# Newspaper3k, User Agents and Scraping

Tags: web-scraping, python-newspaper

I'm making text files consisting of the **author**, **date of publication** and **main text** of news articles. I have code to do this, but I need for `Newspaper3k` to identify the relevant information from these articles first. Since user agent specification [has been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65110807/web-scraping-with-python-and-newspaper3k-lib-does-not-return-data) an issue [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56614991/why-isnt-my-newspaper3k-code-working-with-newsweek), I also specify the user agent. Here's my code so you can follow along. This is `version 3.9.0` of Python.

```
import time, os, random, nltk, newspaper 

from newspaper import Article, Config

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124  Safari/537.36'

config = Config()
config.browser_user_agent = user_agent

url = 'https://www.eluniversal.com.mx/estados/matan-3-policias-durante-ataque-en-nochistlan-zacatecas'
article = Article(url, config=config)
article.download()
#article.html #
article.parse()
article.nlp()

article.authors
article.publish_date
article.text
```

To better understand why this case is *particularly* puzzling, please substitute the link I've provided above with this one, and re-run the code. With [this link](https://www.milenio.com/policia/llegan-300-elementos-de-la-guardia-nacional), the code now runs correctly, returning the author, date and text. With the link in the code above, it doesn't. What am I overlooking here?

Comment: LMK if you still need help with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Newspaper demands that we specify the language we're interested in. The code here *still* doesn't extract the author for some strange reason, but this is enough for me. Here's the code, if anyone else would benefit from it.

```
#
# Imports our modules
#

import time, os, random, nltk, newspaper
from newspaper import Article
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()

# The link we're interested in

url = 'https://www.eluniversal.com.mx/estados/matan-3-policias-durante-ataque-en-nochistlan-zacatecas'


#
# Extracts the meta-data
#

article = Article(url, language='es')
article.download()
article.parse()
article.nlp()

#
# Makes these into strings so they'll get into the list
#

authors = str(article.authors)
date = str(article.publish_date)
maintext = translator.translate(article.summary).text


# Makes the list we'll append

elements = [authors+ "\n", date+ "\n", maintext+ "\n", url]

for x in elements:
    print(x)
```

Comment: The author tag is contained in a script tag, which requires additional code to extract.   I published a [Newspaper Usage Document](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/newspaper3_usage_overview) on GitHub that discusses various collection strategies and other topics surrounding this library.